# Vector field on the circle

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a vector field on the circle, something like:

[image]

Here I have periodic function $f(\theta)$, such  that $f(\theta + 2\pi) = f(\theta)$. The arrows on the circle should point in the direction corresponding to the sign of $f(\theta)$. The figure shows a particularly simple example where $f(\theta)$ has a constant sign.

Comment: $f$ is always real-valued?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, $f(\theta)$ is always real valued and periodic. You can also assume it is smooth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a start. Define a function that gives you a nice arrow based on position, the direction it should look at and a size. This can be done by transforming the coordinates

```
arrowHead[p_, dir_, size_] := 
 With[{pts = 
    size*{{-1/4, 0}, {-1/2, -1/3}, {1/2, 0}, {-1/2, 
        1/3}}.RotationMatrix[-dir]},
  Polygon[p + # & /@ pts]
  ]

Graphics[arrowHead[{1, 1}, Pi/2, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The most simple solution is now to create a table of angles where you want to plot the arrows. For each angle you calculate the `Sign` and use it to calculate the arrow direction. Then draw a circle and over it all the arrows:

```
f = Sin;
Graphics[
 {Thick, Circle[],
  arrowHead[{Cos[#1], Sin[#1]}, #2, .2] & @@@ 
   Table[{phi, phi + Pi/2*Sign[f[phi]]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi - Pi/5, Pi/5}]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When the `Sign` is 0, then the arrows will point outwards.

Depending on your real function `f`, you might want to consider to analyze the regions of angles, where `f` has the same `Sign`. You can then put exactly one arrow directly in the middle. This might be preferable to using a fixed sampling of arrows.

What I mean by that is the following. Assume `f` to be

```
f = Sin[#] + 2 Sin[2 #] &
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you find the roots of your `f`, you can create the ranges. For the given `f`, this can be done by

```
ranges = Partition[
  Sort[N@Values[Flatten[Solve[f[x] == 0 && 0 <= x <= 2 Pi, x]]]], 2, 1]
(* {{0., 1.82348}, {1.82348, 3.14159}, {3.14159, 4.45971}, {4.45971, 6.28319}} *)
```

Now we can calculate the middle point inside each range and create a nice colored circle that has only one arrow for each range

```
inspectRange[f_, {min_, max_}] := 
 Module[{m = Mean[{min, max}], s, col},
  s = Sign[f[m]];
  col = Switch[s, -1, ColorData[96, 1], 1, ColorData[96, 2], _, Black];
  {col, Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {min, max}], 
   arrowHead[{Cos[m], Sin[m]}, m + Pi/2*s, .2]}
  ]

Graphics[{Thickness[.02], Circle[], Thickness[.01],
  inspectRange[f, #] & /@ ranges}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
myArrow[θ_, h_] := 
  Graphics[{Arrowheads[.1], 
    Arrow[Sign[h] {{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {Cos[θ + .05], Sin[θ + .05]}}]}];

h[θ_] := If[θ < .3, 1, -1];
Show[Table[
  myArrow[θ, h[θ]], {θ, 0, 2 π, .2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]